# What is a reliable accreditation to look for in British business schools?

Tags: united-kingdom, business-school, accreditation

When selecting an American business school, we look for certain accreditations specific to business schools, like ACBSP, AACSB, CHEA, , etc.

For European universities, we look for Equis, AMBA, etc.

What about British universities? (For pursuing a PhD in a UK business school.)

Comment: The UK is part of the EU. I know next to nothing about business schools, but AMBA at least is *based in London*. I would expect that many accreditation schemes used in Continental Europe are also used in the UK.

Comment: Presumably, "when selecting an American university..." means "When selecting an American **business school**...".

Comment: @Moriarty *“The UK is part of the EU”* — I suppose, technically, it is :)

Comment: Who looks for these accreditations? My suggestion would be to look for schools with good reputations and not good accreditations.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub how to know about reputation without accreditation?

Comment: @JeffE yes, I mean business school to pursue PhD degree

Comment: @Moriarty what about the myriad UK universities which has no such accreditation. How to know if they had good reputation or global recognition?

Comment: How can I know if the degree will be recognized by other schools if I want to teach or further research?

Comment: You are asking very specific questions that most here will be unable to answer. Your best bet of getting a *rough* idea of an institution's credibility is looking at its world rankings (ie QS or Times Higher Education rankings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how valuable accreditations are. I would suggest going by reputation rather than a binary is/isn't accredited. I think it would be rare for a school to have a "good" reputation, but lack critical accreditations. There likely is variability in the accreditations that schools with questionable reputations have. I would still base my decision on reputation and then only when deciding between a few schools with very similar reputations give any weight to accreditation. As for finding out about reputation word of mouth, league tables (e.g., the [Guradian](http://www.theguardian.com/education/table/2013/jun/04/university-guide-business-management-studies) tables), and the [RAE](http://www.rae.ac.uk/results/qualityProfile.aspx?id=36&type=uoa) are reasonable starting points.

Answer (score 2):

Same as EU: UK has [16 schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_accreditation#UK_.2816_schools.29) with triple AACSB-AMBA-EQUIS accreditation, which is a good sign that it follows the same agencies as the rest of the world (or at least, as the rest of EU).